# Error on bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on Windows 8 64 bits and when i run
**bundle update**, I have this error:

I'm Ruby 2.0.0 and I re-install the RubyDevKit

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:720:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:950:in `block in have_library'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:945:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `block in check_libs'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `each'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `all?'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `check_libs'
        from extconf.rb:39:in `manual_ssl_config'
        from extconf.rb:61:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Someone know what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the gem 'eventmachine' on your system. The command to do that is in the error:

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'
```

This may raise other errors; you'll have to read each and try to work through it.